# Microsoft Azure C#: The type or namespace 'Cosmos' does not exist in the workspace 'Microsoft.Azure'

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to read a Cosmos DB within my Azure C# v2 Function. In order to do so, I need the following import:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
```

However, I receive the following error:

> Using directive is unnecessary. The type or namespace 'Cosmos' does
> not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Azure' (are you missing an
> assembly reference)?

This seems strange, considering that I have already added the package view the dotnet CLI:

> **C:\Users\t-henzhu\Documents\AccessChangeMonitoring\AccessChangeMonitoring>dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos --version 3.11.0**
> Determining projects to restore...
> Writing C:\Users\t-henzhu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp529E.tmp
> info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos'
> into project
> 'C:\Users\t-henzhu\Documents\AccessChangeMonitoring\AccessChangeMonitoring\AccessChangeMonitoring.csproj'.
> info : Restoring packages for
> C:\Users\t-henzhu\Documents\AccessChangeMonitoring\AccessChangeMonitoring\AccessChangeMonitoring.csproj...
> info :   CACHE
> https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.azure.webjobs.host.storage/index.json
> warn : Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions 3.0.5 depends on
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage (>= 3.0.11) but
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage 3.0.11 was not found. An
> approximate best match of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage 3.0.13
> was resolved.
> info : Package 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos' is compatible with all the
> specified frameworks in project
> 'C:\Users\t-henzhu\Documents\AccessChangeMonitoring\AccessChangeMonitoring\AccessChangeMonitoring.csproj'.
> info : PackageReference for package 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos' version
> '3.11.0' updated in file
> 'C:\Users\t-henzhu\Documents\AccessChangeMonitoring\AccessChangeMonitoring\AccessChangeMonitoring.csproj'.
> info : Committing restore...
> info : Writing assets file to disk. Path:
> C:\Users\t-henzhu\Documents\AccessChangeMonitoring\AccessChangeMonitoring\obj\project.assets.json
> log  : Restored
> C:\Users\t-henzhu\Documents\AccessChangeMonitoring\AccessChangeMonitoring\AccessChangeMonitoring.csproj
> (in 525 ms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a solution with a single project or do you have multiple projects and are using project references?

If this is the case, are you adding the package to all projects that will use it? On the SDK we have a sample Function App project that uses the V3 SDK (Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos) and works: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/tree/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/AzureFunctions